# Defining Java interface for JSON object with optional field types

Tags: java, json, typescript, jackson, gson

Is there way in GSON or Jackson to define fields with several possible types in Java? Also, is there a possibility to define optional fields?

The TypeScript equivalent to what I am looking for is:

```
export interface MyInterface {
    myType: string;
    myOption: string | number;
    myPerhaps?: string;
}
```

This is just an example. `string` and `number` could be any object such as `MyObjectOne` and `MyObjectTwo`. Is there a way to achieve that in Java? If not, are there GSON or Jackson annotations built for this?

Possible incoming JSON objects are the following.

Example 1:

```
{
    myType: "abc",
    myOption: 5
}
```

Example 2:

```
{
    myType: "def",
    myOption: "ghi",
    myPerhaps: "jkl"
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to define multiple types in Java, but the best approach would be to try the `Object` class and then cast it later on.

Comment: No, Java doesn't have a union type as TypeScript does. (Note that _most_ strongly-typed languages don't, and for this among other reasons JSON that does this is unfriendly to other developers. In most cases, prefer `"5"`.)